# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token magento 1.9

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.9

_Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
_(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #confirm_password: (More info: goo.gl/9p2vKq) ​ ​

_Uncaught ReferenceError: review is not defined at HTMLButtonElement. ((index):2696) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (b5eacb3bc9fb9c60be961ba5ce6ec5a4.js:6373) at HTMLButtonElement.s (b5eacb3bc9fb9c60be961ba5ce6ec5a4.js:6373) onestepcheckout-numbers-1.gif _Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET onestepcheckout-numbers-3.gif 
_Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) / 
_i have a problem with onestepcheckout on magento 1.9

_its when i make an order on the site it shows like doesn't work or goes on un infinite loop any solution ???

Comment: Have you tried looking at the link in the error? What did you try? Why did it not work? You should provide some code to demonstrate your .issue

Comment: have you written any code, or is this purely based on configuration? Maybe consider editing you question with the details (rather than adding to the comments), to provide a more complete question so people can help.

Comment: No i didn't edit any thing my site it was work correctly but suddenly it stop responding maybe SOME EXTENSION can help @Phil  and i don't know whats make this error

Answer (score 0):

- The first error seems trivial which means basically you have 2 elements having the same Id. Chrome notices and warming about this. So please find out in the template where it is located and change it to be unique because ID means that way.
- Review is not find ... could the actually the problem. It may be because missing some js file which breaks the whole thing. (check browser console)
- Please check where does that comes from. Also you can check what has been change between the time it worked and it broken. It doesn't have to be your code but configuration change, integration change or service provider maintenance can easily causes that issue.
- The images missing doesn't seems to be the main reason there.

Hope it may give you some point to investigate.

Comment: (index):2696 Uncaught ReferenceError: review is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):2696)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (b5eacb3bc9fb9c60be961ba5ce6ec5a4.js:6373)
    at HTMLButtonElement.s (b5eacb3bc9fb9c60be961ba5ce6ec5a4.js:6373)   /////skin/frontend/vt-madealshop/dunes/css/images/ajax-loader.gif:1 GET http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/vt-madealshop/example/css/images/ajax-loader.gif net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET......  this is the browser console , and i didnt change anything of my code what configuration it may cause this error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'down' of undefined
    at addressPreview (b5eacb3bc9fb9c60be961ba5ce6ec5a4.js:11209)
    at (index):3267

Comment: can you turn off merge js ? (in admin or set core config table) to see what actual problem file it is. and it is quite obvious something wrong there in js file so the object is undefined.

Comment: i off the merg js but it still show me the same error , i know the problem is with onesteocheckout but i don't know how to fix it ???\\\\\ onestepcheckout.js:699 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'down' of undefined 
    at addressPreview (onestepcheckout.js:699)
    at (index):3316